# PYTHON- Print Certain Number of Lines in File?

Tags: file

I want my program to read a number of lines determined by the user, but I only know how to make it print a certain number of bytes (stored in fLine). Can someone help me out? Thank you!!

fName = raw_input("hello what file would you like to open?: ")

fLine = int(raw_input("how many lines would you like to print?: "))

try:

```
inFile = open(fName, 'r')
```

except:

```
print "failed to open %s sry" % fName
```

else:

```
line = inFile.read(fLine)
print line
```

inFile.close()

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Python? If yes, try to use [readlines()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) function .